# Accessing a constant from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I have this function inside class firstViewController that produces itemID

```
 func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

     // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
        messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
        return
    }
   //Get metadata object
let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
    if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
    //if the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the the bounds
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
        messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            let itemID = metadataObj.stringValue
            print(itemID)


        }
    }
}
```

I want to call itemID in another viewController called secondViewController. How do I call itemID from the firstViewController inside the secondViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass that on "prepareForSegue".
just make sure you declare itemId as variable on secondviewcontroller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if (segue.identifier == "secondViewControllerSeque") {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            secondViewController.itemID  = self.itemID 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your segueing from the FirstViewController to SecondViewController you can pass the data like this.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondViewControllerSegue" {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
        if let itemID = itemID {
            secondViewController.itemID = itemID
        }
    }
}
```

But don't forget to create itemID variable in FirstViewController and instead write the code like this

```
var itemID: String?


if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
    messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
        itemID = metadataObj.stringValue
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The firstViewController class needs a member variable, itemID. Then the second viewcontroller should be able to reference it.

Right now itemID is a local variable in your captureOutpur function.
This goes away once the function is finished running. Assign it to the member instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a segue, you only need to do this:

FirstViewController (note: use capital letter on name):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowNextView" {        // the identifier is what you named it
        if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            vc.itemID = itemID                     // itemID is accessible here, probably global
        }
    }
}
```

SecondViewController:

```
var itemID:String

func viewWillAppear() {
    // code to use itemID value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just need to follow 3 steps, let's assume you want to pass data from `ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB:`**

1.create a segue between `ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB`

2.name the segue with a Identifier in the attributes inspector of it

3.override the `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender:  AnyObject!) at ViewControllerA`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MySegueID" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewControllerB {
            destination.myInformation = self.myInformation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first declare a variable in FirstViewController.

```
var itemID: String?
```

And call your function to assign your value to that variable before navigation to SecondViewController.

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
    self.itemID = metadataObj.stringValue
   }
```

Now, declare itemIdForSVC public variable in SecondViewController also,

```
public var itemIdForSVC: String?
```

If you are using Storyboard then pass parameter like this while navigating,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if (segue.identifier == "secondViewControllerSeque") {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            secondViewController.itemIdForSVC  = self.itemID 
        }

    }
```

Or if you are doing all programmatically then pass like this while navigating,

```
let secondViewConttoller = SecondViewController()
secondViewController.itemIdForSVC  = self.itemID
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewConttoller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am doing all programmatically. Where exactly in the FirstViewController should I declare the code I seem to be having problem with this                                                                                           let secondViewConttoller = SecondViewController()
secondViewController.itemIdForSVC  = self.itemID
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewConttoller, animated: true)

Comment: you should add this code to the event from where you want to go to next second page, i.e onButtonTapped event.